# What are the VST recorder plug-ins on the market?

Tags: audio-recording, plugins, vst

I would like to record the audio in one point of my session in my VST-compatible host. What are the **free & commercial VST recorder plugin available on the market**?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/archive/effects/2004-02/35651.php

http://www.softpedia.com/downloadTag/VST+recorder

http://www.hgsounds.com/shop/vst-plugins/hgs-wav-recorder-vst-plugin

http://www.loopers-delight.com/LDarchive/200306/msg01128.html

http://flstudio.image-line.com/documents/edison.html

Answer (score 3):

[Voxengo](http://www.voxengo.com/) have a plugin called [Recorder](http://www.voxengo.com/product/recorder/) that does what you want, available for Windows only though. It's free too.

[image: Voxengo Recorder Plugin]

Answer (score 0):

As of 2016 you can add too this VST/AU 32/64bit plugin for Windows & Mac: http://4drx.com/plugins/looprecorder/